# Writing the number '80668227' as a sums of 4 & 5 cubes

Tags: number-theory, number-representation

I need to write the number '80668227' as a sum of 4 & 5 cubes.
I tried this code `PowersRepresentations[80668227, 4, 3]` in Mathematica
but the above code is prolonged. Is there any faster way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes there is a tiny little bit of magic, with a bit of lucky guessing ;}

```
Flatten[Table[
  sol=FindInstance[80668227- x^3- y^3==z^3 + n^3, {z, n}, Integers];
  If[sol=={},{},{x,y,sol}],
  {x,1,50},{y,1,x}]]
```

returns in about 6 seconds

```
{43,28,z->-402,n->526}
```

and

```
80668227==43^3+28^3+(-402)^3+526^3
```

returns

```
True
```

instantly

And

```
Quiet[Do[
  sol=FindInstance[80668227-x^3-y^3-z^3==n^3+w^3,{n,w},PositiveIntegers][[1]];
  If[sol!={},Print[{x,y,z,n/.sol,w/.sol,x^3+y^3+z^3+(n/.sol)^3+(w/.sol)^3}]],
  {x,1,25},{y,1,50},{z,1,y}]]
```

will show you some five variable positive solutions

Comment: It's much useful. Thank you! But what if we need to get the answer only in positive integers?

Comment: `Flatten[Table[sol=FindInstance[80668227-x^3-y^3==z^3+n^3,{z,n},PositiveIntegers]; If[sol=={},{},{x,y,sol}],{x,1,100},{y,1,x}]]` I URGE you to learn the art of writing a question in the form that the readers will know exactly what solutions will be acceptable before they begin.

Comment: Sure, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This gives answers instantly.

```
FindInstance[80668227 == x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + n^3, {x, y, z, n}, 5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Verification of  of one

```
{x,y,z,n}/.sol[[1,1]]
Total[(#^3)&/@%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Same for the sum of 5 cubes

```
FindInstance[80668227 == x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + n^3 + m^3, {x, y, z, n, m},5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Yes, but I need the answer in integers only. Thank you!

Comment: @Littlewood  it won't work for integers. Mathematica is not magic. It took one million hours on super computer to solve $x^3 + y^3 +  z^3 = 42$ for integers, and was done by brute search. see [this](https://interestingengineering.com/science/the-sum-of-three-cubes-problem-for-42-has-just-been-solved) so I do not see Mathematica being able to solve this for integers just like this.

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP does not specify the conditions on the numbers (from a comment above only positive integer solutions seems to be of interest). 42 is a completely different and much more complicated story because the solution is in terms of integers (actually 2 positive and 1 negative). The solution space is unbounded and therefore they are much more difficult to find. The OP problem is an easy one as the answer of @Bill demonstrates.